# Free disk Nagios plugin using python

Tags: nagios

IF there anyone can help me to modify the script below. I'm trying to use the Python script to check for 
disk space alert on the filesystems, but as a right now the script ONLY check the root "/" filesystem. I would to check with the script all the filesystems available on the servers. This is for a nagios filesystem disk space and the script only check "df /". If any one can help into find the solution to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re,sys,commands

#################
#Set variables
command = "df /"
critical = 95.0
warning = 75.0
#################

#build regex
dfPattern = re.compile('[0-9]+')

#get disk utilization
diskUtil = commands.getstatusoutput(command)

#split out the util %
diskUtil = diskUtil[1].split()[11]

#look for a match. If no match exit and return an
#UNKNOWN (3) state to Nagios

matchobj = dfPattern.match(diskUtil)
if (matchobj):
    diskUtil = eval(matchobj.group(0))
else:
    print "STATE UNKNOWN"
    sys.exit(3)

#Determine state to pass to Nagios
#CRITICAL = 2
#WARNING = 1
#OK = 0
if diskUtil >= critical:
    print "FREE SPACE CRITICAL: '/' is %.2f%% full" % (float(diskUtil))
    sys.exit(2)
elif diskUtil >= warning:
    print "FREE SPACE WARNING: '/' is %.2f%% full" % (float(diskUtil))
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print "FREE SPACE OK: '/' is %.2f%% full" % (float(diskUtil))
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nagios already comes with a filesystem disk space check.  My first recommendation would be to use it.

To answer your specific question, the script is running "df /", so you'll only get the results of that filesystem.

Why not run just "df", which will return you multiple rows, which you can then loop across?

You might also consider writing it in native python:

```
s = os.statvfs('/')
(s.f_bavail * s.f_frsize) / 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the result for `/` because that is explicitly called out in the statement `command="df /"`

You could: 
a) substitute a command line option for `/` in `command="df /"` that lets you pick the partition
b) make multiple versions that looked explicitly for different partitions `/, /home, /var`, etc.
c) use the nagios built in
d) write it in shell/awk, since you just want to evaluate the output from a shell command